# VB.NET BindingSource ListChanged event not firing if DataTable not on same form

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I've got a `DataGridView` that I'm binding to a `BindingSource` to a `DataView` to a `DataTable`. When rows are added to the `DataTable` I want the changes to appear in the `DataGridView` automagically, like they're supposed to. Standard stuff.

If I put the `DataTable` instance on the same form as the `DataGridView`, the `BindingSource`'s `ListChanged` event fires and the `DataGridView` refreshes. But if I put the `DataTable` anywhere else, like in a module or on another form, the `ListChanged` event won't fire and the `DataGridView` won't refresh automatically unless I minimize and restore it's form. Why?

**Update**

Here's an example of how I'm doing this in a simple test app:

The module:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Module modTick
    Private WithEvents tmr As System.Timers.Timer
    Private r As New Random()

    Public dt As DataTable

    Public Sub Init()
        dt = New DataTable("table")
        dt.Columns.Add("Number")
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {r.Next})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {r.Next})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {r.Next})
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartTimer()
        tmr = New System.Timers.Timer()
        tmr.AutoReset = True
        tmr.Interval = 500
        tmr.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub _tmrPulse_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles tmr.Elapsed
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {r.Next})
    End Sub
End Module
```

The form:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private dv As DataView
    Private WithEvents bs As BindingSource = New BindingSource()
    Private WithEvents tmr As Timer = New Timer()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        modTick.Init()

        dv = New DataView()
        dv.Table = modTick.dt
        dv.AllowDelete = False
        dv.AllowEdit = False
        dv.AllowNew = False
        dgdisplay.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        bs.DataSource = dv
        dgdisplay.DataSource = bs

        tmr.Interval = 500
        tmr.Enabled = True
        modTick.StartTimer()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmr_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmr.Tick
        Label1.Text = bs.Count
    End Sub
End Class
```

So, if I put the module's code in the form, the `DataGridView` refreshes because the `BindingSource`'s `ListChanged` event fires. As-is, it neither fires, nor refreshes. But if I minimize and restore the form, the changes are there. The `Label` shows the number of items in the `DataTable` and this is correct.

Comment: Could you show a simple example of the code where the binding is being setup?